# Build error with Room database cannot resolve

Tags: android, android-room

I am at a loss to find this build error what does this mean?

```
Expected ':' at line 31 column 15 path $.database.entities[0].fields[3].fieldPat11
```

I cannot track the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you have an error in JSON parsing. Kindly check your model class. or share your more code.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin or which piece of code to submit? It is a fairly big piece of code and the error is at build time, this is the only feedback i am getting?

Comment: Ok. Kindl shares your API response, a model class of API response and code in which you have written this line '$.database.entities[0].fields[3].fieldPat11'.